# PHPExcell Cell coordinate can not be zero-length string

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel via the Zend framework and want to read entire Excel files into an array of data. I downloaded the final release from [this page](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/archive/develop.zip).

The code I am using is as below :

```
static function Read_Excel($inputFileName)
{
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);      
    $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);    
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
    $highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
    if($highestRow <=0 || $highestColumnIndex<=0)
        return false;
    $arr_data = array();
    for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row ++) {
        for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; $col ++) {
            $value = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue();
            if (is_array($arr_data))
                $arr_data[$row - 1][$col] = $value;
        }
    }
    return $arr_data;
}
```

And I get this error:

```
 Message: Cell coordinate can not be zero-length string
Stack trace:

#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\library\PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php(935): PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString('')
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\application\models\Functions.php(30): PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007->load('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...')
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\application\controllers\ImportController.php(56): Application_Model_Functions::Read_Excel('C:\xampp\tmp\ph...')
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\library\Zend\Controller\Action.php(516): ImportController->indexAction()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\library\Zend\Controller\Dispatcher\Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('indexAction')
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\library\Zend\Controller\Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\library\Zend\Application\Bootstrap\Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\library\Zend\Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\wimax.shabdiznet.com\public\index.php(25): Zend_Application->run()
#9 {main}
```

I have searched a lot but found nothing! How can I resolve the problem ?

Comment: The error Ocures in Load function at line 4

Comment: Something is clearly wrong, but it's almost impossible to identify what from this: having downloaded the code you pointed to, line 935 of PHPExcel\Reader\Excel2007.php is an `} else {` (not a call to PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString()) so I can't see what part of the code is causing the error, and without the ability to test using the same file as yourself, there's no way of trying to identify the cause

Comment: Take the file from here : https://www.dropbox.com/s/ca8fwoq6c3ey8ar/22.xlsx              also talks on github with developer here :  https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/177#issuecomment-17761415

Answer (score 1):

you definde cell is too short, you can add some cells
like this:

> $cell = array('A1','B1','C1','D1','E1','F1','G1','H1','I1','J1','K1','L1','M1','N1','O1','P1','Q1','R1','S1','T1','U1','V1','W1','X1','Y1','Z1');